# Facebook "Invite Friends Page"

Tags: facebook

Is there anyone knows the step by step how to make a Facebook "Invite Friends Page"... In the official page i can't find any clear explanation about this... And also they said that fbml will be deprecated after 2010... So, how will the Facebook "Invite Friends Page" run after 2010?...

Comment: what do you mean by invite friend page? you want a friend selector?

Comment: @awais:everything to build an iframe which is generated by facebook in order the user could be able to invite their friends to the apps...

Comment: have you tried friend selector?

Comment: i don't know how to start to use it... im using i frame based apps...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean invite friends from a website outside of FB you do it with JS:

From the [facebook developers website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Something like this should work:

```
FB.init({
        appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        frictionlessRequests: true,
      });

function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
      FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My Great Request', 
      }, requestCallback);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok then use this

```
<fb:serverFbml width="760px">
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml>
      <fb:request-form
            action='http://apps.facebook.com/yoursite/'
            method='POST'
            type='photo fun'
            content="Let's fun with facebook
        <fb:req-choice url='http://www.yoursite.com' label='Register'/>"
        <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Select your friends."></fb:multi-friend-selector>
     </fb:request-form>
   </fb:fbml>
  </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

Although this is in fbml but facebook is providing still support. As for as i know facebook has not provided any kind of replacement still. So enjoy it to use